# Что значит "!1"?

Tags: javascript

```
let $scrollTrigger = !1,
    lastSl, mobile = !1
```

Comment: это значит false

Comment: значит `false`. Но так булеву никто не пишет (исключение когда надо привести к типу переменную и одновременно конвертировать это в булеву). А за то, что написано выше  руки надо отрывать

Comment: Yesn't.........

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @СергейМишин, Если посмотришь коды разных библиотек, то такую запись будешь видеть не так редко). Но в чем сакральный смысл именно такой записи не знаю.

Comment: @Lukas приведение к типу и потом её же к булевой - норма. Например приходят данные и пишешь `let test = !!externalVariable`. В библиотеках как правило именно это.. А `!1` никто не пишет. Это нонсенс. Это как каждый раз вместо того, чтобы сказать НЕТ, говоришь - НЕ ДА

Comment: @СергейМишин, ну не пишут - так не пишут)

Comment: @Lukas, как правило это результат минификации

Comment: Есть, кстати, такая штука как [subfactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). Записывается как `!n`. И совпадение: `!0 = 1`, `!1 = 0`. Случайность, конечно.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Теперь хоть понятно откуда это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Бит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82) может находиться в одном из двух устойчивых состояний.

одно `true` - логическая единица или "не ноль". [В булевой (или логической или двоичной) алгебре](https://function-x.ru/buleva_algebra.html) обозначается, как `1` . В электронике сигнал того, что на участке схемы есть напряжение около `2` вольт (на разных платах по разному).

второе `false` - логический ноль или "не единица"  [В булевой (или логической или двоичной) алгебре](https://function-x.ru/buleva_algebra.html) обозначается, как `0`. В электронике сигнал того, что на участке схемы есть напряжение около `0.2` вольт (на разных платах по разному).

`!` - обозначает логическую операцию `отрицание` или `инверсию` сигнала в электронике и, соответственно `инверсию переменной` в программировании. Есть еще `~` — логическая операция отрицания над отдельными битами.
Логические операции в электронике реализованы с помощью [логических элементов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B).
То, что `!0 === 1`, а `!1 === 0` (Не логический ноль тождественно равен логической единице и наоборот) является одной из (если не ошибаюсь) 4 [аксиом двоичной алгебры](https://ru.bmstu.wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0#.D0.90.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.BC.D1.8B)

Соответственно из [таблицы истинности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E.&text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5,%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85.) логического отрицания, которая есть в третьей ссылке, можем узнать, что `!1` обозначает `0` или `false`

Comment: `!` обрабатывает булевы значения как целый объект. `~` обрабатывает отдельные биты  в числе. Я бы поостерёгся начинать ответ со слова 'бит', вы запутываете ТС.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, согласен немного путано вышло. Но как еще объяснить, что такое true и false, не начиная с бита?.

Comment: По разному можно. В JavaScript `true` и `false` значения отдельного типа `boolean`, которые ведут себя подобно битам.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy И все равно мы приходим к битам или тому, как реализованы состояния бита в языке.